# ikev2 handshake : 4 or 8 packets?

Tags: ipsec

I open wireshark to inspect the ikev2 handhsake and noticed it is 8 packets instead of 4. Two groups of 4 packets, one originating from the first peer and the other from the second peer. Is it normal ? Shouldn't it be one 4-packet exchange only ? (note : i am using tunnel mode esp)

Answer (score 1):

To quote [cisco.com](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/115936-understanding-ikev2-packet-exch-debug.html),

> [Unlike IKEv1] the IKEv2 exchange is variable. At best, it can exchange as few as
> four packets. At worst, this can increase to as many as 30 packets (if
> not more), depending on the complexity of authentication, the number
> of Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP) attributes used, as well
> as the number of SAs formed.

So, eight packets is within acceptable range for an IKEv2 negotiation.